# Return ID from LINQ after multiple attaches/insert

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a Sub that takes a lot of values and updates/creates the records in the database as necessary.

```
Public Sub BatchChange(ByVal Updated As List(Of Article), ByVal Created As List(Of Article), ByVal Deleted As List(Of Article), ByVal UserId As Integer)

        Dim d As DateTime = Now

        For Each Art As Article In Deleted
            Art.Deleted = True
            Art.ChangeDate = d
            Art.ChangeCount += 1
            DB.Articles.Attach(A, True)
        Next

        For Each Art As Article In Created
            Art.ChangeDate = d
            Art.ChangeCount = 1
            Art.ModifierUserId = UserId
            DB.Articles.InsertOnSubmit(A)

            Next

            For Each Art As Article In Updated
                Art.ChangeDate = d
                Art.ChangeCount += 1
                Art.ModifierUserId = UserId
                DB.Articles.Attach(A, True)

            Next

        DB.SubmitChanges()

End Sub
```

Now this in turn has to be synced to another database through a REST-API and my current issue is with the For Each in the "Created" model.

```
    Public Sub BatchChange(ByVal Updated As List(Of Article), ByVal Created As List(Of Article), ByVal Deleted As List(Of Article), ByVal UserId As Integer)

        Dim d As DateTime = Now
        Dim SyncList As New List(Of SyncParam)

        For Each A As Article In Deleted
            A.Deleted = True
            A.ChangeDate = d
            A.ChangeCount += 1
            DB.Articles.Attach(A, True)
            SyncList.Add(New SyncParam(A.ClientId, A.ArticleId))
        Next

        For Each A As Article In Created
            A.ChangeDate = d
            A.ChangeCount = 1
            A.ModifierUserId = UserId
            DB.Articles.InsertOnSubmit(A)
            SyncList.Add(New SyncParam(A.ClientId, A.ArticleId))
            Next

            For Each A As Article In Updated
                A.ChangeDate = d
                A.ChangeCount += 1
                A.ModifierUserId = UserId
                DB.Articles.Attach(A, True)
            SyncList.Add(New SyncParam(A.ClientId, A.ArticleId))
            Next

        DB.SubmitChanges()

        For Each Value In SyncList
            API.Util.APISync(Value.ClientId, Value.ArticleId)
        Next

    End Sub
```

And I need the created ID for the Article so I'm looping through the list after DB.SubmitChanges in the vain hopes of retrieving it and then sync it with the other database.

But apparently this way isn't possible, it keeps complaining that the row has been changed/modified or removed which I'm assuming it has since LINQ has updated the values.

How can I loop through the list (with the modified values) without VB Net complaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the Created object did contain the ID after DB.SubmitChanges so the answer was to make a new For Each loop after that and pull the ID

```
Public Sub BatchChange(ByVal Updated As List(Of Article), ByVal Created As List(Of Article), ByVal Deleted As List(Of Article), ByVal UserId As Integer)

    Dim d As DateTime = Now
    Dim SyncList As New List(Of SyncParam)

    For Each A As Article In Deleted
        A.Deleted = True
        A.ChangeDate = d
        A.ChangeCount += 1
        DB.Articles.Attach(A, True)
        SyncList.Add(New SyncParam(A.ClientId, A.ArticleId))
    Next

    For Each A As Article In Created
        A.ChangeDate = d
        A.ChangeCount = 1
        A.ModifierUserId = UserId
        DB.Articles.InsertOnSubmit(A)
        Next

        For Each A As Article In Updated
            A.ChangeDate = d
            A.ChangeCount += 1
            A.ModifierUserId = UserId
            DB.Articles.Attach(A, True)
        SyncList.Add(New SyncParam(A.ClientId, A.ArticleId))
        Next

    DB.SubmitChanges()

    For Each A as Article in Created
       SyncList.Add(New SyncParam(A.ClientId, A.ArticleId))
    Next

    For Each Value In SyncList
        API.Util.APISync(Value.ClientId, Value.ArticleId)
    Next

End Sub
```